# Preventing extra fields from being added to a asp.net form

Tags: asp.net

I realize what I am trying to do is a little unconventional; but I want to make my search SEO. Basically I want the query string resulting from my search to be human readable; if I was doing straight html this would be cake:

```
<form method="GET"><input type="text" name="Zip" /></form>
```

I realize that I can change the form method in asp.net, however, all the asp.net state holders show up in the query string. I even tried disabling viewstate and removing all javascript submitting controls (to get rid of __EVENTTARGET) to no avail.

The thing is, I really want to keep using the same master page as I do in the rest of the site; does any one know of anything I can do short of building the page from scratch?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `runat="server"` in your form tag to get rid of `__EVENTTARGET`, however then you lose the reason for using WebForms.

Comment: But I want to keep using the SAME MASTER PAGE, and I need to runat="server" for the rest of them

Comment: Move to ASP.NET MVC then, WebForms is based on something you don't want. I recommend you switch frameworks.

Comment: Ah, fux it; I'll just have to resort to some javascript haxory :(

Answer (score 0):

As Rick Schott stated, you should consider ASP.NET MVC. Then you'll have no __EVENTTARGET no __VIEWSTATE no auto-generated id'S (although it's easily disabled). You can even have ASP.MVC working in the same project as classic ASP.NET.

Try it [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)